# How come I have different reputations on the main and the meta?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

How can it happen that I have 126 reputation points on the main and only 124 on the meta?

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reputation on meta is synchronized once per hour, so it can vary a bit between main and meta site when your reputation changes on the main site.